# jQuery validation either no value or length of 4 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to know if it's possible to set the jQuery validate properties to either skip validation if there is no value in the textbox or if there is some value then the value should be exactly 4 characters.

Something like:

```
txtObject: {
                     //put validation properties here
                    },
```

Is that possible?

Comment: FYI:  The jQuery Validation Engine and the jQuery Validate plugin are two different things.  Please be more mindful when tagging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to set the jQuery validate properties to either skip validation if there is no value in the textbox or if there is some value then the value should be exactly 4 characters.

To skip validation when the field is empty simply means that you should NOT use the `required` rule; making the field "optional".

All other rules are only evaluated when the field is not empty.

Setting the `minlength` and `maxlength` rules to `4` will meet your specification.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  // <-- ensure form's HTML is ready

    $("#test-form").validate({  // <-- initialize plugin on the form.
        // your rules and other options,
        rules: {
            field_name: {  // <-- this is the name attribute, NOT id
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 4
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5v2cspp7/**

Answer (score 0):

```
        txt_edit_pass_werk_email: 
        {
            minlength: function(element){
                if($("#txt_edit_pass_werk_email").val() != "")
                {
                    return 8;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            },
            maxlength: 12
        }
```

I did stumble on the same problem as u did. So I did found this post. I figured it out myself. So here is the solution wich works perfectly for me with jquery validation and conditional fields:
If the field txt_edit_pass_werk_email is NOT empty.. then the field has validation with minlength 8. if the field is empty, the minlength is zero. This is conditional validation.